# iTunes trying to sync every app I have on my Mac?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

This is driving me mad.

I've been keeping my iPhone and iTunes in sync for ages, and today all the the sudden iTunes tries to sync every single app on my Mac to iPhone, instead of just the one I installed.

I reset all contents and setting, restored my phone from iCloud, saw the list of my old apps, then plugged the phone back in. Again, iTunes starts syncing every one of my app back to the phone.

Any idea to get rid of this crazy behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of the change of iTunes apps layout or the apps couldn't be determined

Check here for more information 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3395256?start=210&tstart=0

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2744493?start=45&tstart=0

> 2enjoy
>   Re: Sync Apps from iphone to itunes changes the apps layout
>   Sep 14, 2012 10:00 PM (in response to CybermanSG)
>   so who wants the real answer??  its very simple...
>
> as mentioned, first of all TRANSFER PURCHASES from iphone to itunes. check the SYNC APPS check button. yes this will cause itunes to reorganise your folders (for now), however, then close itunes. you will get a window pop up asking if you want to apply the changes. Select YES. itunes will then close. now re-open itunes and PRESTO!  itunes will now show all of your apps as selected and they will all be in the same folders as in your iphone. you can now sync away without losing your personal folders...
>
> this was done on a iphone 4S running 5.1.1 on itunes 10.7.0.21
>   hope that helps.. enjoy!